# If $y_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n}$ converges to $L$, than so is $x_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that if
> $$ y_n = \frac{x_1+\cdots + x_n}{n}$$
> has a finite limit, then $x_n$ has the same limit as $y_n$.

Intuitively it is easy to understand. There are infinite number of $y_i$ which are extremely close to it’s limit (let us call it $a$), then it is really intuitive why limit of $x_n$ has to be $a$ too. If it wasn’t then either we would have different limit or we wouldn’t have limit at all.

I am pretty bad in such formal proofs, so all hints and help will be appreciated!

Comment: It is entirely possible for $x_n$ to have no limit. But if $x_n$ has a limit, it must be the same as the limit of $y_n$.

Comment: This is false. We can even have an unbouded sequence $(x_n)$ such that $(y_n)$ has  a finite limit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy and what would the counter example be? Something like $(-1)^n$?

Comment: @math-traveler Yes, $(-1)^{n}$ is not convergent but the corresponding $y_n$'s tend yo $0$.

Comment: For an unbounded example, take a sequence that is mostly $0$, but occasionally (such as whenever $n$ is a power of $2$) is $\log n$.

Comment: P.s: the series with $x_n = (-1)^n$ is also known as [Grandi Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2446109).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. If you take $x_n =(-1)^n $ then $$|y_n | =\left|\frac{x_1 + x_2 +... x_n }{n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}\to 0$$
and hence $$y_n \to 0$$ but $x_n $ does not converges to $0.$

But the reverse theorem is true. Namely if $x_n \to a$ then $y_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 +... x_n }{n} \to a.$